# git clone from github authentication problem (ask for username and password)

Tags: git, ubuntu, clone

When I use command git clone at ubuntu this massage appear to me [username and password for github account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bz8tD.png)
and this account is not mine , I just git clone from this account
what should I do ?
anyone can help ?

I am trying the git credential manager but I don't know how to use it

Comment: show your full command

Comment: when I write a command (sudo git clone https://github.com/pwnlandia/mhn.git) 
the I use the command of installation (sudo ./install.sh) 
this appear to me 
(Running command git clone -q https://github.com/threatstream/hpfeeds/ /opt/mnemosyne/env/src/hpfeeds-dev

Username for 'https://github.com': 

Password for 'https://github.com': 
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.)
how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Just in case, do you have a github account ? Or adding your ssh key in https://github.com/settings/ssh/new ?

Comment: I'm tried the ssh key , but it is don't ask me about my account username and password , 
this ask me about the username and account that I am want to install the (MHNserver)
fromt it 
I try to login in with my account but refuse ! 
so what should i do to install the server ?

Answer (score 2):

to log in on your GitHub in the command line, try using **[github-cli](https://cli.github.com/)**.

then easily with the `gh auth login` command login to your GitHub account at the first time, then it will be automatically store your authentication data in your machine and you can do git stuff like clone, push, pull, etc.

Comment: I already tried this way but this massage appear to me 
"remote: Repository not found.

fatal: repository 'https://github.com/threatstrean/hpfeeds/' not found"
I tried the ssh auth also it don't work also 
so what should i do to install (MHNserver)?

Comment: because this link that you sent actually does not exist, maybe you selected the wrong link!

Comment: I know , but this link existed in the file of installation of MHNserver when i type the command (sudo ./install.sh) it is automatically install the server but this problem appear to me look the sequence that i follow at ubuntu 18.04
 Frist ( sudo apt install git -y)
2- (sudo git clone https://github.com/pwnlandia/mhn.git)
3- (sudo ./install.sh)
the problem appear at this step of installation